# VBA- Unable to update SharePoint 2013 item via REST API

Tags: excel, vba, rest, sharepoint-2013

I am attempting to update a SharePoint item via REST API, though I am receiving the below error:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, System.InvalidOperationException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The type of data at position 0 is different than the one expected."}}}

I'm not quite sure what is causing this- I have the request type set to JSON, but it does not seem to accept my input. Any help is appreciated :-)

My code:

```
Sub Work_Damn_You()

Dim oXMLHTTP As Object

Dim sListNameOrGuid As String
Dim sBatchXml As String
Dim sSoapBody As String
Dim sWTF as string

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

sListNameOrGuid = sListName

With oXMLHTTP
    .Open "POST", "http://SPSITE.COM/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('PAGE')/items(22)", True
    .setRequestHeader "X-RequestDigest", testerino
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose"
    .setRequestHeader "__metadata", "(""type"":""SP.Data.QATrackerListItem"""

    sWTF = """preTestComment""=""Hello"""
    .send (sWTF)

    Debug.Print (.responseText)

    ' Check response
    If .Status = 200 Then

        Debug.Print .Status & " [Happy Days!]"

    Else
        Debug.Print .Status & " [Sad Days :-(]"
    End If

End With
Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing

End Sub
'''
```

Comment: `"(""type"":""SP.Data.QATrackerListItem"""` are you missing a closing parenthesis?

Comment: ...and shouldn't that be part of the request Body?

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams. I added the closing parenthesis, and tried to include it in the send request. The new error is : "The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetById"